# Windows Phone adding eventhandler from different classes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

Using this code, i am adding an eventhandler to the RootFrame.Obscured.

```
(Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += onObScured;
```

Since the RootFrame can be accessed from every class in the App, what happens if i add different eventhandlers from different classes?
Example:

```
class A{
    (Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += onObScuredA;

    private void onObScuredA(object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e) {
        //Some code here
    }
}

class B{
    (Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += onObScuredB;

    private void onObScuredB(object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e) {
        //Some other code here
    }
}
```

When the event is triggered, will both onObScuredA() and onObScuredB() be triggered if there has been created an instance of both A and B?
Is the correct way, to add the eventhandlers, and their respective methods on the App.xaml.cs class so i can be certain which eventhandlers are added?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many event handlers onto an event as you want, they will all be invoked. That is the nature of events, when they fire, all event handlers handle this event.

So, the answer is "they both will be triggered". Now, this may or may not be what you want, but adding new event handler does not replace previous event handlers.

Read more on MSDN: [Handling and Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx).

Comment: So if i add something like this.myvar = "hello" to an event, it will throw an exception if no instance of the class exist and set myvar to "hello" for every object created of the current type? If no instance of A has been created, the method onObScrutedA will never be added to the eventhandler?